# Detect indexes of a dataframe from values contained in another dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I have 2 dataframes:

```
# dataframe 1
data = {'Name':['PINO','PALO','TNCO' ,'TNTO','CUCO' ,'FIGO','ONGF','LABO'],
        'Id'  :[  10  ,  9   ,np.nan ,  14   , 3    ,np.nan,  7   ,np.nan]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and

```
# dataframe 2
convert_table = {'XXX': ['ALLO','BELO','CACO','CUCO','DADO','FIGO','FIGO','ONGF','PALO','PALO','PINO','TNCO','TNCO','TNCO','TNTO']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(convert_table)
```

My goal is to identify the indexes of the elements of `df2['XXX']` which follow these conditions:

- Are present in `df1['Name']`
- Have the correspondin `df1['Id'] = NaN`

I was able to achieve my goal by using the following lines of code:

```
nan_names = df1['Name'][df1['Id'].isnull()]

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for name in nan_names:
    index = df2[df2['XXX']==name].index.tolist()
    if index:
        dic = {'name':[name] , 'index':[index]}
        df3 = pd.concat([df3,pd.DataFrame(dic)], ignore_index=True)
```

However I would like to know if there is a more efficient and elegant way to achieve my goal.

The result should look like this:

```
          index  name
0  [11, 12, 13]  TNCO
1        [5, 6]  FIGO
```

Note: if the name is not found then, it is not needed to store any information.

Comment: Not necessarily... in this example yes but in general there may be some repetitions

Comment: Actually I deleted my comment and decided to go with your `nan_names`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the method `isin`:

```
df = df2[df2['XXX'].isin(nan_names)]
```

This will return:

```
    XXX
5   FIGO
6   FIGO
11  TNCO
12  TNCO
13  TNCO
```

From there it's just a matter of formatting:

```
df.reset_index().groupby('XXX')['index'].apply(list)
```

This will return:

```
XXX
FIGO          [5, 6]
TNCO    [11, 12, 13]
```

The idea is to reset the index so that it becomes a column (named `index`). Grouping by name and applying the `list` function will return the list of original indices for each name.

Calling `reset_index` once more will return the result you were looking for.

---

**Edit**

Combine everything into a one-liner, this will be the output:

```
In [21]: df2[df2['XXX'].isin(nan_names)].reset_index().groupby('XXX')['index'].apply(list).reset_index()
Out[21]: 
   XXX         index
0  FIGO        [5, 6]
1  TNCO  [11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: could u please add somehow "inplace=True" option in order not to redefine df?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean. You can assign the final result to `df3` like this: `df3 = df.reset_index().groupby('Name')['index'].apply(list).reset_index()`. In that case `df` is just a temporary variable. You can avoid using `df` by replacing it by its definition, which will give you a long one-liner.

Comment: I noticed that the index column is not present? How is it possible?

Comment: Like in my question: the names of the columns are: Name and Index; however in your answer there is only the the name of the Name column

Comment: I modified the problem to make it slightly more general but the answer should be modified accordingly... I changed convert_table column name in XXX; could you please update the answer?

Comment: Sorry about that... is that I thought that my problem was generic enough but then I found out it is somehow a special case... thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `apply` `list`:

```
nan_names = df1.loc[df1['Id'].isnull(), ['Name']]
print (nan_names)
   Name
2  TNCO
5  FIGO
7  LABO

df = pd.merge(df2.reset_index(), nan_names, on='Name', suffixes=('','_'))
print (df)
   index  Name
0      5  FIGO
1      6  FIGO
2     11  TNCO
3     12  TNCO
4     13  TNCO

print (df.groupby('Name')['index'].apply(list).reset_index())
   Name         index
0  FIGO        [5, 6]
1  TNCO  [11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: I modified the problem to make it slightly more general but the answer should be modified accordingly... I changed convert_table column name in XXX; could you please update the answer?